# How do I get the equipment in the "Good Ol' Days" quest?

Tags: half-minute-hero

In the "Good Ol' Days" level I can see that there is a piece of equipment that I did not get, but neither town is selling one. It looks like there is some sort of code I'm supposed to put into the west forest, but I can't figure out how or if it's related. What do I have to do to get the equipment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this level, the forests just south of the east-west mountain range are shaped like an NES controller, as the picture shows.

[image: Controller forests]

To access the secret, enter the code

> Up Down Right Left B A B A

by walking on to each corresponding space in order, and without walking onto any other code space in between. Each code space can only be activated if you step on it after it turns sepia. Each step that correctly activates a code space will be accompanied by a tone and the game will pause temporarily, and each incorrect step will be accompanied by a different tone and the code will reset. The following path will correctly input the code:

[image: Controller forests path]

Once the code is properly input, a cave will appear at the center of the + shape of trees and on the other side is a town where a girl will give you glasses. Be careful because if you reset time after you enter the code, the cave will disappear and the code can *not* be reentered.